# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass but I have used an instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, view, controller

I'm new to ruby and to rails and I realize this is a basic question but i've searched everywhere and tried other's suggestions for this error.

I'm getting this error

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

However I've used @ in the controller to make the array an instance variable

controller

```
  def a_list
    #Gibbon::Request.lists("9225cefb61").retrieve
  list = Gibbon::Request.lists("9225cefb61").members.retrieve(params: {"fields": "members.email_address"})
  list_hash = list.body
  a= list_hash["members"]
  @result_array= a.map { |email_array| email_array['email_address'] }
  end

view 
<%= "list emalis"%>
<br/>
<% a_list%>
<% @result_array.each do |item| %>
  <%= item %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `a_list` method is called in this controller action? Could you show the full stacktrace and the actual source of the controller action?

Comment: Must be this view is rendered from another action, not `a_list`

Comment: what's `a_list`? an action or a helper method? because it sounds like an action but you call it manually inside the view, why don't you just do `a_list.each do |item|` on your view since you are actually calling the method there?

Answer (score 1):

The error is because when the controller performs a different action, instance variables like that don't necessarily carry over / get set, and any undefined instance variable defaults to `nil` value. Assuming that this list view is on `ResultsController#show`, one option would be for `ResultsController` to look something like:

```
before_action :a_list, only: :show

def show
  # Any other code for show
end

def a_list
  list = Gibbon::Request.lists("9225cefb61").members.retrieve(params: {"fields": "members.email_address"})
  list_hash = list.body
  @result_array =  list_hash['members'].map { |ea| ea['email_address'] }
end
```

This uses the built-in [Rails Filters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) to handle the execution of the message chain while displaying your view. Since `#a_list` is run before `#show`, the value of `@result_array` makes it down to the view.

Answer (score 0):

As @Justin P. explained, you should use filters as that's the best way.

Another(faster) solution would be to move `a_list` code to corresponding action you're calling from view. That way you will get proper @result_array that you're trying to access in your view.

Cheers.